# How does an HMAC work, and why isn't this code generating the right response?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hmac, sha256

I'm trying to figure out how HMAC's work. Here is the documentation from [AWS-S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html)

```
signing key = HMAC-SHA256(
  HMAC-SHA256(
    HMAC-SHA256(
      HMAC-SHA256("AWS4" + "<YourSecretAccessKey>","20130524")
      , "us-east-1"
    )
    , "s3"
  )
  ,"aws4_request"
)
```

The documentation says,

> You can use this example as a test case to verify the signature that your code calculates; however, you must use the same bucket name, object key, time stamp, and the following example credentials:

I don't understand how the Node core [crypto module](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) works or how to read the HMAC spec.

Would it be right to describe the above like,

```
var h1 = crypto.createHmac( 'sha256', "AWS4" + 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY' );
  h1.setEncoding('hex');
  h1.write( '20130524' );
  h1.end();
var h2 = crypto.createHmac( 'sha256', h1.read() );
  h2.setEncoding('hex');
  h2.write( 'us-east-1' );
  h2.end();
var h3 = crypto.createHmac( 'sha256', h2.read() );
  h3.setEncoding('hex');
  h3.write( 's3' );
  h3.end();
var h4 = crypto.createHmac( 'sha256', h3.read() );
  h4.setEncoding('hex');
  h4.write('aws4_request');
  h4.end();
console.log( h4.read() )
```

And, if so.. Why do I get back,

> d949da6fe2897897d73557446db35c06dc34feb7f74e7d949c6fe9d674a02103

And, not that which is given in the docs:

> aeeed9bbccd4d02ee5c0109b86d86835f995330da4c265957d157751f604d404

I've also tried to write this a different way too, because I'm not sure how subsequent calls to `.write()` are handled

```
var h1 = crypto.createHmac( 'sha256', "AWS4" + 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY' );
  h1.setEncoding('hex');
  h1.write( '20130524' );
  h1.write( 'us-east-1' );
  h1.write( 's3' );
  h1.write('aws4_request');
  h1.end();
  console.log( h1.read() );
```

So I guess I have two questions

1. Based on [the AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html) what code does it take to get the signature given in the examples...
2. What is the function of successive calls to .write() on a crypto stream? It doesn't append. And, it doesn't wrap in a new HMAC-SHA256.

Answer (score 3):

I just spent 16 hours trying to figure this out and I got a working solution, based on your initial steps. Not the most elegant code but it works! See below.

Also, this is my first Stack Overflow post! So pardon any formatting mistakes!

```
var policy = {
  "expiration": "2020-12-01T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "XXXTHISISYOURBUCKETXXX"},
    ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
    {"x-amz-credential": "XXXTHISISYOURPUBLICKEYXXX/20150107/us-west-1/s3/aws4_request"},
    {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
    {"x-amz-date": "20150107T000000Z"}
  ]
};

var base64Policy = Buffer( JSON.stringify( policy ) , 'utf-8' ).toString( 'base64' );

var a = crypto.createHmac( 'sha256' , 'AWS4' + 'XXXTHISISYOURSECRETKEYXXX' );

a.write( '20150107' );

a.end();

var b = crypto.createHmac( 'sha256' , a.read() );

b.write( 'us-west-1' );

b.end();

var c = crypto.createHmac( 'sha256' , b.read() );

c.write( 's3' );

c.end();

var d = crypto.createHmac( 'sha256' , c.read() );

d.write( 'aws4_request' );

d.end();

var e = crypto.createHmac( 'sha256' , d.read() );

e.write( new Buffer( base64Policy , 'utf-8') );

e.end();

var signature = e.read().toString( 'hex' );

console.log( signature );

var credentials = {

  policy : base64Policy,
  signature : signature

};
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is more of a comment, but since I can't comment as a guest:]

Not sure if you need the setEncoding() call at that point. Just let it process, and call:

```
signature = hmac.read().toString('base64');
```

as the return output from `hmac.read()` is of type `Buffer`, so the `toString()` works fine on it.